# Ajax function inside JavaScript is not getting called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to render the template called reset_password_page.html using AJAX. I intend to send some data to this template. The problem is that page is not getting loaded. It gets loaded when I use location.href, but this cannot be used as I won't be able to send any data to the template.

```
function trial() {
  if ("{{ verified }}" == "yes") {

   document.getElementById('lbl_verify').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('lbl_verify2').style.display = "none";

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "{% url 'reset_password_page' %}",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
          async: false,

        });
      });

    }, 1000);

  } else {

  }
}
```

views.py

```
def reset_password_page(request):
  return render(request,"reset_password_page.html")
```

Comment: `if ("{{ verified }}" == "yes") {` will never be true because it is just comparing string

Comment: It is working because I tested it with 'alert' . verified is a variable from the view.py .Up to that point the code is correct.

Comment: Please show the alert code

Comment: I edited the code . The style changes in my code actually take place. only the ajax is not working.

Comment: What does `{% url 'reset_password_page' %}` evaluate to?

Comment: I didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

Its due to the if condition used.You are comparing 
if ("{{ verified }}" == "yes")
which is false.
try if ({{ verified }} == "yes") which will fetch verified value.

Comment: I edited the code . The style changes in my code actually take place. only the ajax is not working